# Creating Temporary lists for Each set of user inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I am trying to create temporary lists to store individual weekly data for each store(I ask the user what the name of your store is and then ask about their daily sales for the week, which I then want to append into a separate list, but I don't know how to do it for multiple user inputs, which all have different sets of daily data for the week), I have created a permanent list to store all store's data in one list. I am trying to create temporary lists for each store's data so that I can make a 2D list as a requirement in my project. I hope you understand.

```
All_Store_Daily_income = []
days_of_the_week = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
is_last_weekday = None

def get_daily_store_data():
    Day_Counter = 0
    while Day_Counter < 7:
        try:       
            Daily_sales = float(input(f"What is the income for {days_of_the_week[Day_Counter]}? "))
            All_Store_Daily_income.append(Daily_sales)
            print(All_Store_Daily_income)
        
            Day_Counter = Day_Counter + 1
            global is_last_weekday
            is_last_weekday = Day_Counter == 7
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a integer or float, no letters allowed!")


def store_adder_programme():
    Store_name_list = []
    number_of_stores = 1
    Adding_stores = 'y'

while Adding_stores == 'y':

    store_name = input("What is the name of your registered store? ")
    Store_name_list.append(store_name)
    get_daily_store_data()
    print(Store_name_list)

    if (is_last_weekday == True) and (Adding_stores == 'y'):
        print('Would you like to add a new store?')
        Adding_stores = input("If YES(y), If NO(n): ")
        print(All_Store_Daily_income)                        
        number_of_stores = number_of_stores + 1

store_adder_programme()
```

Comment: Would you like a list that looks like this for example: `{"Monday" : [{"Store name " : "Store 1", "Store Revenue" : "$100,000"}, {...}], "Tuesday" : [{}, {}] }` Because that is very possible. However, this kind of data structure is usually less favorable to having a seperate list for each day of the week and then assigning to a dictionary. I can post an answer if this seems to be what you want?

Comment: So I was meaning a separate list for the whole week of data if that makes sense, instead of for each day, so it would be easier to retrieve the values for each store(this was a requirement for my project) if this helps any better for what I'm looking for. But the way that you said is also very efficient, so I could try that for a permanent list

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Could you provide a pseudocode example, or just the general data structure you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it. I put some inline comments to help explain what I did.

```py
All_Store_Daily_income = []  # this becomes 2D list

days_of_the_week = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
                    "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
is_last_weekday = None


def get_daily_store_data():
    seq = []  # create a list

    Day_Counter = 0
    while Day_Counter < 7:
        try:
            Daily_sales = float(input(f"What is the income for {days_of_the_week[Day_Counter]}? "))

            seq.append(Daily_sales)  # fill list with store data

            Day_Counter = Day_Counter + 1
            global is_last_weekday
            is_last_weekday = Day_Counter == 7
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a integer or float, no letters allowed!")

    return seq # return list


def store_adder_programme():
    Store_name_list = []
    number_of_stores = 1
    Adding_stores = 'y'

    while Adding_stores == 'y':
        store_name = input("What is the name of your registered store? ")
        Store_name_list.append(store_name)

        store_data = get_daily_store_data() # get list from function return value

        All_Store_Daily_income.append(store_data)  # append returned list to All_Store_Daily_income

        print(Store_name_list)

        if is_last_weekday and Adding_stores == 'y':
            print('Would you like to add a new store?')
            Adding_stores = input("If YES(y), If NO(n): ")
            print(All_Store_Daily_income)  # prints the 2D list
            number_of_stores = number_of_stores + 1

store_adder_programme()
```

Comment: thank you so much, been trying this for like 3-4hrs straight and couldn't get it. Just got into python 4 weeks ago

Comment: @AvinashRajaram no problem, glad I could help.